# Solve $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+4x) - 4x}{x^2}$ without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

### I tried solving $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+4x) - 4x}{x^2}$ without L'Hopital like this:

---

### $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+4x)^{\frac {1}{4x}4x} - 4x}{x^2}$ = $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{4x\ * \ln(e) - 4x}{x^2}$ = $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{0}{x^2}$

and that is undetermined. And I have no other idea on how to solve it. Please help, and remember, WITHOUT L'Hopital rule. Solve just with simple limits manipulations, aka no Big O notations, series, integrals etc.

Comment: Can you use Taylor series? In particular $$\ln{(1+x)}\sim x-\frac12x^2\quad (\text{as }x\to0)$$

Comment: Nope, can't use that.

Comment: If you can use the sandwich theorem then try using $$x-\frac12x^2\le\ln{(1+x)}\le x-\frac12x^2+\frac13x^3$$

Comment: @PeterForeman, well your using of sandwich theorem is indeed based on the Taylor expansion so you've just changed the Taylor series into this form and it's not what can be used without any knowledge of power series.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhôpital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: Thank, that answers my question completely, post it as an answer so I can give it a tick @labbhattacharjee

Answer (score 3):

replace $x$ by $-x$ & add then we get,

$2L=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1-4x)+\ln(1+4x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\ln(1-16x^2)}{x^2}=-16\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\ln(1-16x^2)}{-16x^2}\implies L=-8$

Answer (score 1):

Integrate
$$
\frac{1}{{1 + t}} = 1 - t + \frac{{t^2 }}{{1 + t}}
$$
from $0$ to $4x$ to obtain
$$
\log (1 + 4x) = 4x - 8x^2  + \int_0^{4x} {\frac{{t^2 }}{{1 + t}}dt} 
\\
 = 4x - 8x^2  + (4x)^3 \int_0^1 {\frac{{s^2 }}{{1 + 4xs}}ds} .
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{{\log (1 + 4x) - 4x}}{{x^2 }} =  - 8 + 4^3 x\int_0^1 {\frac{{s^2 }}{{1 + 4xs}}ds}  \to  - 8
$$
as $x\to 0$.

Comment: I can't use this because we haven't learnt it, I can use only limits manipulations or sandwich theorem.